# Sql query to firebase query. How to add data to existing data without replacing it

Tags: sql, firebase

I want to conver this sql query:

```
UPDATE Table SET Field=CONCAT(Field,'extra data');
```

Into a Firebase query. I have no idea how to do it.
Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: That's not a query, that's an assignment. What do you want to query for? What's platform are you coding on? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thank you Jay. I'm using JavaScript and I notice that a lof of people was having a difficult time consulting the Firebase database. Hence, check this video: "Common SQL Queries converted for the Firebase Database" -> goo.gl/nFk5Yq Query number 8 is... 0.o Well, you can read the comments. For that reason and because it seems that Firebase could be a bit complicated to work with, I decided to post this question. Although I should've include more details about what I wanted to do.

Comment: Ok. So.... include more details about what you are trying to do. Provide us a snippet of your Firebase structure (as text please, no images) and describe what kind of data you are wanting to fetch. You can edit your question by clicking the Edit link right underneath the question. Firebase is no more complex than SQL is - it's just another way to store and retrieve data.

Comment: "Firebase is no more complex than SQL is - it's just another way to store and retrieve data." That's kind of like saying that Mandarin is no more complex than English is - it's just another language. In firebase ["You can only use one order-by method at a time. Calling an order-by method multiple times in the same query throws an error."](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/web/lists-of-data)  Therefore, ["whenever you structure data in the Firebase database, you want to do so with your queries in mind."](https://youtu.be/sKFLI5FOOHs?t=10m22s)

Comment: You have to think in advance in ALL the possibles querys you might have to do in the future. Not with SQL. Any how, I was going to include more details in my question but I don't see it necessary. I think is pretty straightforward. Translate an SQL query into a Firebase database query.

Comment: After using SQL for.... almost 30 years, I find Firebase to be no more or less complex. It still requires data modeling, planing and methods for storing and retrieving data. Just like you would do with SQL. My original comment still stands. Your question is an assignment statement, not a query; that's why it's received 6 down votes (none from me). If you can update your question with an actual query, then we can take a look at doing it in Firebase. Also, please include a snippet of your Firebase structure so we can understand what the data looks like. On, and what result do you want?

Answer (score -1):

I came up with this. Not sure if there's a better way of doing it.

```
 function UpdateUserData(userId, calories) {
 return firebase.database().ref('/phases/' + userId).once('value').then(function(snapshot) {

             var more_calories = $('#more_calories').val();

             var calories = snapshot.val().calories;
             var actual_calories_plus_added_calories = calories + more_calories;

             firebase.database().ref('/phases/' + userId).set({
                 calories: actual_calories_plus_added_calories
             });

             UpdateUserData(userId, calories);
```